How much time for peer-review of a paper by a self-taught new academic?
Suppose I have an elementary solution to P vs NP problem. It doesn't uses any cutting edge techniques or ideas, it only uses well-established contemporary concepts, structures and inferences. And the paper is as clear, concise and rigorous as can be.
Although - I haven't published anything before, I am new and I am self-taught(no formal degrees), and have no experience in academia.
For how long the peer-review process can go on ? Considering the results and proofs are really airtight, and use only those concepts which are well-established in mathematics, computability and complexity theory.
Also - what if I have also found an inconsistency in ZFC, and that paper shows an explicit contradiction, basically airtight again..
How much time would the peer review process take if I try to publish the results to a reputed journal ?
The main reason for asking is that I expect that given the proofs are so concise , elementary and rigorous , so there is a chance they may get accepted within 6-8 months.

You can expect to get a negative reply very quickly, probably in a matter of days. If the editor and the reviewers are nice, they will also explain where the error is (but they may reject it on the grounds of not being written clearly). How many pages of text are we talking about?

You should just make your proof publicly available, for two reasons. First, perhaps there will be an expert who will take the time to look at it and tell you where the error is. Second, on the miniscule probability that you both solved P vs. NP and found an inconsistency in ZFC at the same time, it will be quite important that there is public record of your authorship.

@AndrejBauer suppose i make the proofs public, say on arxiv or researchgate, and the other people in the field actually found the results and proofs to be correct.... and then i submit it to a journal.....  you think it will get accepted... quickly ?

@AndrejBauer the only thing my proof falls short of is that it says nothing about why 3sat is in np and 2sat is in p, i just create an explicit decision problem and show it must not have a polynomial solution, and that too only for (deterministic) UTM, for some reason i have doubts regarding quantum machines....

Your fears of your work being stolen are completely unecesasry. If you post on arXiv, that will be a record of your authorship. If someone tried to steal your work and get it published in a journal, then once it is found that they stole the work (based on the avidence in arXiv) they will (1) lose all respect, (2) the journal will retract the paper, and (3) they will probably be sanctioned by their university. However, you need not worry about all this. You need to worry about your paper having a mistake – that is much, much, much more probable.

@AndrejBauer that is actually reassuring. But , and i dont know how else to put it, i have decided to take 3-4 more years before i publish the proof, i just feel like that i should atleast take some online degree or course that atleast guarantees that i learn how to write papers in professional academic style.  I am just 25 , and i still know that atleast the proof sketch doesn't have any errors, i just want to make more connections, understand the rules, and then write a paper which atleast shouldn't be rejected on grounds such as poor writing or inexperience....

If you invest extra years in learning how to do mathematics because you like to do mathematics, then that is a great idea. If you are obsessed with your proof and you think it is worth investing 3-4 years of your time just to improve the proof, then that is a bad idea. Every mathematician will tell you of numerous times when they thought they had a proof, were willing to bet anything that it worked, but it was of course wrong. Failure is the norm. I still think you could easily publish your proof and get it over with, either way. That will allow you to concentrate on better things.

"i just want to make more connections, understand the rules" That's great! I would start small, by trying to make sure you fully understand how small mathematical facts are proved, then move on to more complicated ones, etc.  Pick up any proof-based undergraduate textbook with exercises on any mathematical topic you like and work through it thoroughly. (The "proof-based" part excludes many calculus textbooks which are intended more to train people how to compute things.) Discrete math is generally a good place to learn about mathematical proofs.

@AdamPřenosil i have to confess, there are a big number of posts on stackexchange itself enquiring how to get published without formal training.. i wonder if they ever did achieved their goals.. this does makes me think if my proof actually has any errors. But i've been working on this for about 8 months now, my proof sketch sure has went through some minor technical changes, that too only in looking for formal concepts to pin it down, but the core argument remains the same, couldn't found any error in that... well anyways... i do like pure maths, so will give a couple of years to it first

I encourage you to worry more about whether your proof is correct and less about the time for peer review.    If you are an outsider to the field, it's very unlikely that you have a correct solution to P vs NP, and doubly unlikely that you also have found an inconsistency in ZFC.  It's far, far more likely that you have fooled yourself.
If you really want to know how long it's likely to take, we can't answer that, as it depends on the journal/conference and on the quality of your work.  If you submit to a conference in theoretical computer science, most conferences list the deadline for submission and the date by which they will notify you of their decision.  If you submit to a journal, I suspect the most likely answer is that you will receive a rapid response with a desk rejection, but if not, the amount of time is unpredictable and heavily dependent on the journal and the particular reviewers, so it's just not answerable.  It could be 3 months, it could be 12 months, it is not easy to predict.
That said, if you are worrying about the time for a response, you are worrying about the wrong thing.  It is far far more likely that your "solution" is flawed, but you haven't realized it yet.  As Richard Feynmann wrote, the easiest person to fool is yourself.

More broadly: Before asking further questions, I strongly recommend that you read the following resources:

I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?
Ten Signs a Claimed Mathematical Breakthrough is Wrong
What steps would an amateur scientist have to take in order to get a scientific breakthrough published?
What should one do if they've discovered a "breakthrough" but lack academia credentials?
How can an independent researcher publish a well-written research paper / proof in a respected mathematical publication?
Crackpot research paper in mathematics
Is there a single example of an outsider considered a "crank" publishing a ground-breaking result that was found to be correct (in the last 30 years)?
How do professors perceive breakthroughs from outside academia?

You don't have to agree with any of that or see it as applying to you.  If nothing else, it will help you to understand the reactions you receive, and if you're smart, it will help   you figure out how to navigate the situation.  Recognize that researchers in this field have seen dozens or hundreds of people claiming the same thing as you, and they've all turned out to be mistaken, so researchers are likely to start with a very strong prior that you are probably mistaken too.  This may help you anticipate likely reactions and what you need to do to be successful.

i get it why anyone thinks i must have made an error, but this is the real situation - the proofs are so much easy (yes) that just a little, tiniest hint or a clue and I know for a fact that there are thousands (if not millions) of people in this field who will crack the proof in a matter of days (if not hours), write a more experienced (i don't know how to put it in any other way) paper, and publish it themselves. They will have the privilege to be taken more seriously given there previous works. This includes many here in stack exchange community itself.

i myself have no shame in admitting that it was 80-90% shear luck, maybe no one was willing to look in this direction, maybe the fact that i am not trained formally lead me to approach it in a very unlikely way, and it actually worked. But nevertheless, once you get to know , even a hint of the direction or the approach you will find the problems trivial. So give me a break if i appear to be a bit paranoid when it comes to revealing the details about the proofs publicly just yet

@AdityaMishra, Please see my revised answer.

thanks for the resources... really appreciated.

This is not how academia works. If you post your putative proof on any online repository, you will have proof of priority and no-one will be able to "scoop" you. Plagiarism, which would include appropriating your proof and rewriting it in a "more experienced" way, is taken seriously in the international mathematical community. However, beware that what's happening is certainly not that you found two completely ground-breaking results on your own without any formal training in advanced mathematics. Rather, you are misunderstanding some key aspect of the rules of mathematical proof.

Note that this is entirely understandable: it takes years to train students of mathematics to produce reliable, meaningful mathematical proofs, and during most of that period what they produce are not proofs but rather pseudo-proofs, i.e. things that they believe to be proofs but where some key step is missing, or misunderstood, or misinterpreted. This happens even when they are trying to prove some fairly banal things, not necessarily P != NP. If you are imagining you completely skipped this phase of producing "pseudo-proofs" instead of actual proofs, you are 100% mistaken.

@AdamPřenosil i too have started to believe that i am worrying unnecessarily, thanks to all the responses in this post. Plus, as mentioned in this wikipedia page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem  andrew wiles first proof for the FLT also contained an error and it took him an year to correct the proof to the satisfaction of the mathematical community...
